# i want to custom keyboard image send via textdocumentproxy

Tags: custom-keyboard

it shows null .custom keyboard image send via textdocumentproxy.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *mas;
NSTextAttachment* onionatt = [NSTextAttachment new];
onionatt.image = onions;
onionatt.bounds = CGRectMake(0,-5,onions.size.width,onions.size.height);
NSAttributedString* onionattchar = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:onionatt];

NSRange r = [[mas string] rangeOfString:@"onions"];
[mas insertAttributedString:onionattchar atIndex:(r.location + r.length)];
NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",mas];
[self.textDocumentProxy insertText:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send image via uitextdocumentproxy

In custom keyboard you have to copy the image in pasteboard and then manually paste into textfield by using this code:

```
NSString *shareImageName = @"cross.png";
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:shareImageName];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```